# Moved Web Server: Cant Send Email to Own Domain

Tags: php, email, mediatemple

I have encountered this issue on several occasions and was wondering if anyone knows how to fix it.

Basically, after migrating a website to a new server, I am unable to send emails to my own domain.

For example, if I own meowmix.com and try to send an email using PHP on the server to anything@meowmix.com, it doesn't go through. I am assuming it's being blocked as spam or something. I can send to any email address as long as it isn't from the domain that the website is on.

How would one fix this? (LAMP + Plesk environment)

I checked a few other posts asking the same question, and they either want the script to be modified (shouldn't be necessary) or they say "ask your administrator to fix it" (I AM the administrator though...uh oh!)

Bonus love for anyone who can answer this same problem, except when only a partial server migration is moved: bascially, the previous server's A record points to a different server for hosting files (but all other records remain the same).

Cheers

Comment: Better suited for Server Fault.

Comment: It's often the case when this is happening that the mail agent sees: "hey that's an email for me!" and tries to do a local delivery

Comment: Needs migration to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Your SPF records should be updated to include the new server as a legitimate sender.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I had a feeling that may be the case. I'll try doing this later today, and if it works, I'll mark your answer as correct :) Cheers

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble doing this. There doesn't appear to be any existing SPF records, so I am not sure what to add.